# DBeaver - SQL - No result using multiple - (dash) in the where statement

Tags: sql, dbeaver

I assume this could be some setting issue. When I used something like below, I got no result

```
where name = 'hello-world-new'
```

However, if I changed it to below, I got result (because indeed there is data)

```
where name like 'hello-world%'
```

Does anyone know where to check/change the setting?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the exact string in your first where actually exist in the name column? The number of dashes in a where statement has nothing to do with your results. The name field could be nothing but a row of dashes and the query would work (as long as there as the same number of dashes of course).

Comment: @Dave yes, it does exist (not exactly what I put here, but there is data with 2 dashes in between strings). I'm just confused, because my colleague was able to get results using the 1st where. We both use DBeaver.